# How to modify your uploaded website in netlify?

Tags: javascript, html, web, netlify

For example, you have uploaded a website for free using netlify. And then you changed some codes but  after that do you have to upload another new website in netlify or you can just modify the earlier website. If so then how?

Comment: You can create a new GitHub repository and create a new website

Comment: Yes, Netlify will help you to deploy and host your front end codes from git repository like `Github` `Gitlab,` `Bitbucket`!  When you update your system/code from a git repository, it will deploy as soon as possible in netlify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reupload, and it will modify the earlier website

Use the same process that you used for the first website upload. Try it and see, it will change on the website.